# PostgreSQL - Have one serial type column but reset every day (unique combination with other date type column)

Tags: postgresql

i need to have this table that will have a serial type column in my PostgreSQL database that will reset every day and will be unique combination with other date type column.

For example today i insert 2 rows

SerialId, Date

1, '08.12.2016'

2, '08.12.2016'

But tomorrow the next insert should be with SerialId = 1 and tomorrows date

1, '09.12.2016' ...

The problem is that not only one users makes inserts in this table and i can't have some global variable in my application that will count and reset every day.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would just let the sequence keep running, but if you really want to reset it, you could define a `cron` job that runs at midnight and issues

```
ALTER SEQUENCE ... RESET;
```

If the application is really busy around midnight, you have a race condition there, because there is no guarantee that the sequence will be reset precisely at midnight, but if there is not much traffic at this time you might get away with it.